# mssql-jdbc version 6.2.2.jre8 dependency results in version 6.1.0.jre7 in war

Tags: java, maven

I have the following dependency in my Maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
    <!-- Exclude unused Azure dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I am using the newest non-preview mssql-jdbc release in Maven here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc

However when I run `mvn clean package` my resulting war file has `mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` instead of the expected `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar`. I have tried clearing my local `.m2` repository and repackaging but that did not help. It is worth noting that `6.1.0.jre7` is actually the oldest version out there, so my guess is that for some reason it cannot find the newest one and is reverting to the oldest? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered same problem, and I am using Spring Boot 1.5.x.

The root cause is: Spring Boot(1.5.x) specified the version of "6.1.0.jre7".

Solution is: specify your version in the main module which contains Spring boot Application.

Previous part of my dependencies:

Sub module 1:

```
<groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
<artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.3.jre8-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

Main module, which contains Spring boot Application:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I found Main module boot.jar included "mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar".

Finally I found the version is specified in "spring-boot-dependencies" which is the parent of "spring-boot-parent".

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>

<mssql-jdbc.version>6.1.0.jre7</mssql-jdbc.version>
```

Solution:
Specify the version in main module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.3.jre8-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

Checked the result by mvn denpendency:tree, it's ok